# change query by using <href>

Tags: php, href

I have set a default query

```
$query = "SELECT Image, ISBN, Name, Vol, Release_date, publisher, price  FROM products p order by Name,vol";
echo "<a href = ???>Date</a>";
```

so that the query can be changed in sorting by date after clicking?
Thank you!

Comment: several solutions for your problem, depending on the behavior you are expecting. The most naive and insecure way is to run your query on a PHP page different from where your `href` is located and point the link to your new page

Comment: not expected in this way.. i want to return the query in its own page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting/ordering parameter is `order by Name,vol` at the end of the query.
So you might make it as a variable depending on whether the `GET['date']` is present from href.

```
<?php
$sortvar = isset($_GET['date']) ? 'order by '. $_GET['date'] : 'order by Name,vol'; 
if (isset($_GET['ndsn']) &&  isset($_GET['date']) ) 
    $sortvar =  'order by '. $_GET['date'] . ',' . $_GET['ndsn'];     
$query = "SELECT Image, ISBN, Name, Vol, Release_date, publisher, price  FROM products p " . $sortvar;

echo "<a href = '?date=Date'>Date</a><br>";
echo "<a href = '?date=Date&ndsn=NDSN'>Date & NDSN</a><br>";
echo $query;
```

## IMPORTANT

you MUST escape GET parameters or parametrize your result query when adding GET parameters into it, cause of SQL-injections possibility.

Comment: how about if i want to have 2 sortings? (name, ISBN)

Comment: imo i would not use `$_GET['date']` in the order by. Just set 'order by date` if the get is set.

Comment: @DarkBee, using $_GET['date'] makes code flexible so if you want to pass some values, say actual date/time...

Comment: Its enables user to inject stuff in the SQL that OP does not want. Don't give to much freedom to users.. It's like if u'd do something like include($_GET['data']); .. it's way too much freedom

Comment: @DarkBee, but in general, this is more informative for a new user who learns how to use GET parameters from href.